# Return from a while loop without exiting it python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

I know it is not possible. Return will exit it. Is there a way to make it possible. I have while loop and it counts the values. I want to return the value from the while loop and use it for further processing and get back to the while loop again and continue where it stopped. I know the return will exit the loop. How to make it possible.

Here's the sample code:

```
import datetime
import time
def fun2(a):
    print("count:", a)
def fun():
    count = 0
    while 1:
        count = count+1
        time.sleep(1)
        print(count)
        if count == 5:
            return count
a = fun()
fun2(a)
```

My Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
count: 5
```

Required Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
count: 5
6
7
8
9
and goes on....
```

Comment: Use `generator`

Comment: Actually, `yield` instead of return

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seems like you need a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators). The generator will remember the value and `yield` it when it is divisible by 5 (which I assumed by looking at your output) on calling `next`, and will remember the older state, until you call `next` on it again. Also note that this is an infinite generator.

```
def fun():
    count = 0
    while True:
        count = count+1
        print('inside fun', count)
        if count % 5 == 0:
            yield count

f = fun()
print(next(f))
print(next(f))
```

The output will be

```
inside fun 1
inside fun 2
inside fun 3
inside fun 4
inside fun 5
5
inside fun 6
inside fun 7
inside fun 8
inside fun 9
inside fun 10
10
```